# emberjs {{#if variable }} boolean will not display as true

Tags: model-view-controller, ember.js, controller, conditional-statements, handlebars.js

I set a simple boolean (isEditing) in the 'categories' controller to equal 'true' when the
{{action "edit" this}} button is clicked.

The variable will not set itself to true when 'edit' is clicked. I console.log'd to make sure 'edit' knew i was clicking it, and it did. This seems so simple in the emberjs website and i don't know why im having such trouble with now.

categories controller

```
VpcYeoman.CategoriesController = Ember.ArrayController.extend({
    isEditing: false,
    actions: {
        editingyeah: function(){
            console.log('Testing console'); //this works
            this.set('isEditing', true); //this doesnt change to true since the {{Else}} is what is being rendered.
        }        
    },

});
```

categories.hbs

```
    {{#each}}
      <tr class="people-list">
        <td>
          {{#if isEditing}}
          {{view Ember.TextField valueBinding=name}}
          NOOOOOOOO
          {{else}}
          <div class="category-text"> 
          {{view Ember.TextField valueBinding=name}}
            {{#linkTo 'category' this}}
              {{name}}
            {{/linkTo}}
          </div>
          {{/if}}  
          <img class="table-img" src="images/x.png">
          <img class="table-img" {{action "editingyeah" this}} src="images/pencil-grey.png">          
        </td>
      </tr>
    {{/each}}
```

Comment: Is the value not being set, or is the template not being updated? Try doing `console.log(this.get('isEditing'))` directly after you set it.

Comment: The console returns 'true'. IsEditing is true. Shouldnt {{#if isEditing}} be true as well and render the first Ember.TextField?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's because you are looping through each category, so the context within the `each` helper is your category. It's looking for an `isEditing` property on the category, not the one you have in the controller.

Since you are passing the category in to the action, you can access it as an argument in the action's function, and set the property on the category instead:

```
actions: {
    editingyeah: function(category){
        category.set('isEditing', true);
    }        
}
```

Comment: +1 You could do it this way, or you could specify an item (object) controller. I tend to avoid modifying individual item properties within a collection (array) controller because it can get a little messy.

Answer (score 1):

I saw your problem after I posted my comment. You don't have an `isEditing` variable defined in your scope. You're using the `#each` helper, which changes the scope of the template. You either have to keep the scope when using `#each`, or use a `#with` helper.

```
{{#each item in model}}
    {{! isEditing is available now }}
    {{! But you have to do item.name instead of name}}
{{/each}}
```

Or

```
{{#with this.isEditing as isEditing}}
    {{#each}} ... {{/each}}
{{/with}}
```

Comment: This solution also worked, but I ended up using the one above